# How do I write first order numerical method for finding power?

Tags: power, electric-machine

I'm new in this just taking the lectures on YouTube according to this, a self learner you can say
I'm stuck in a problem of how to write numerical method for finding power of motor in the given set of table
[image: question]

[image: table]

Can anyone please help me.

Comment: Linear interpolation ought to do it. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_interpolation

Comment: Where did this problem come from? You should provide a source.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it has little to nothing to do with electrical engineering.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few methods you can use to find the values of P1, P2 and P3. The easiest method would be to plug your current values into excel and run a linear regression, and then substitute your voltage values (30V, 70V and 90V). This will give you *okay* results, but the data looks quite non-linear so you'll definitely have some error.

Another method would be to linearly interpolate the neighbour values around the missing values you're interested in. So, for example you would take 30V as the average of 550 and 70 (310W), 70V as 1335W, 90V 1625W. You could even use a method like

[https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lanczos_resampling][1]

This will give you the best results (use a window of 2), but it will be the most complicated to implement

Answer (score 1):

This is not an EE question *per se*.  The data series you show are not "obviously" linear, so I would eschew linear regression methods [for example, 50V vs 100V -- a doubling -- triples the power (610->1800), *but* 20V vs 40V -- also a doubling -- results in 70->550, *way more* than a tripling].

I highly suggest you start here: Go to http://numerical.recipes/book/book.html and start with chapter 3 "interpolation and extrapolation" and after having read/browsed thru that, go to chapter 15 "modeling of data" and between those 2 chapters you should have a good "gist" of what's involved.  You can read the chapters online for free.